# tengo un problema al sincronizar gradle

Tags: android, gradle

[image: gradle sync]

actualice android studio a la versión 4.0 y ahora me aparece este error

Comment: Intenta actualizando el gradle.

Comment: @Riven ya lo he intentado pero no me deja actualizar a la ultima versión, porque me arroja otro problema

Comment: Como último recurso puedes intentar crear un nuevo proyecto en esa versión de Android Studio, de primeras no debería darte errores ya que debería estar correctamente configurado para dicha versión. Luego copias el código del anterior proyecto al nuevo y listo. Además comparar los archivos .gradle de las dos versiones podría darte una pista de dónde se encuentra el problema.

Comment: lo he intentado pero también me da otro error, es te el error que me da: A problem occurred configuring root project 'Example'